# Hooking into computer mainboard

Tags: hardware

Would you be able to hook th Pi up to a computers motherboard?

I was wondering because of the small amount of resources on the RPi and wondered if it would be able to tap into the RAM and CPU on the mainboard as well as the HDD/SSD or Optical drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer? No. Considering the Pi and traditional desktops nowadays use completely different architecture, there's no way you can do a simple 'plug and play' solution.

Even if you were to consider it, you would most likely need to re-engineer the connections and the boards on both computers to be able to 'hook in' and that just becomes unfeasible because at that point you're better off just using a regular computer to do what you wanted to do.

Comment: What would I have to do to add a hard drive then?

Comment: You mean add a hard drive to the Pi?

Comment: Yeah like would I just have to use a USB port? Or could I use GPIO

Comment: You have to use a USB port. To use GPIO you would need to program a driver and find some way to interface with the hard disk and again this becomes too complicated. Here's a tutorial http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-add-usb-storage-to-the-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thanks :D I have something to use... ill put it together soon